# loop not iterating through list vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops, foreach

The list seems to be only selecting the first cell in the list, can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Everytime I run this, it takes the first cell in the list assigns that value to the cell in ATL tab (which will then run numerous formulas) and copies the range that I want and pastes on the Final tab. I want it to do this, but it will not move down the list to the other cells. I have about 40 cells that it should be iterating through, but it simply won't work. Any ideas?

```
Dim x As Integer
Dim List As Range
Dim intcount As Integer
Dim DCs As Worksheet
Dim Form As Worksheet
Dim Final As Worksheet
Dim DCdata As String
Dim wsList As String
Dim rnglistrange As Range


With ThisWorkbook
    Set DCs = .Sheets("List1")
    Set Form = .Sheets("ATL")
    Set Final = .Sheets("Final")
End With

DCs.Select

    intcount = DCs.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '--Get last row of list.
    Set List = DCs.Range("A1:A" & intcount) '--Qualify our list.

For Each rnglistrange In List '--For every name in list...
        Form.Select
        Range("A2") = List.Value
        Range("A632:N646").Copy
    Final.Select
    ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
    Selection.Offset(2, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in:

```
Range("A2") = List.Value
```

that would just put first value of `List` `range` in cell "A2"

while you want to put:

```
Range("A2") = rnglistrange
```

which would put *current* `List` cell `Value` in cell A2

but you may also want to consider this refactoring of your code, which has the main goal to avoid `Select`/`Selection`/`Activate`/`ActiveXXX` pattern in favor of fully qualified range references to both not loose control over what you're actually referencing and improve performance (and screen flickering)

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim listRng As Range, listCell As Range
    Dim DCs As Worksheet, Form As Worksheet, Final As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook 
        Set DCs = .Worksheets("List1")
        Set Form = .Worksheets("ATL")
        Set Final = .Worksheets("Final")
    End With

    With DCs
        Set listRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp)) '--Qualify our list.
    End With

    For Each listCell In listRng '--For every name in list...
        With Form
            .Range("A2") = listCell
            .Range("A632:N646").Copy
        End With
        With Final
            With .Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(2)
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
                :=False, Transpose:=False
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you, that is beautiful. I definitely wouldn't have been able to come up with that! haha. I appreciate it!

Comment: you are welcome. well now you _are_ able to do that. and more to come

Answer (score 0):

Line 25 of your listing says:

```
Range("A2") = List.Value
```

Change that line to:

```
Range("A2") = rnglistrange.Value
```

You will see then that it is iterating through the cells of your "List" range.